# How to silence "whose type uses the anonymous namespace [-Werror]" gcc version 4.8.2

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, gcc-warning

In one of my project's header file, the following line is included in a `inline` method

```
typedef boost::archive::iterators::transform_width<boost::archive::iterators::binary_from_base64<      boost::archive::iterators::remove_whitespace<std::string::const_iterator>>, 8, 6> Base64ToBin;
```

When I compile this with gcc 4.8.2 I'm getting the following error:

> error: ‘boost::archive::iterators::remove_whitespace<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >’ has a field ‘boost::archive::iterators::remove_whitespace<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >::’ whose type uses the anonymous namespace [-Werror]

I'm really hitting hard but could not resolve this issue, also from the [link1](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53184) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948158/warning-anonymous-namespace-inside-struct-using-function-pointer) it looks like it is an issue with lower version of gcc. Can somebody suggests how to silence this warning or get over with that. I'm using -Werror flag compilation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks like a correct warning. Because the code is in a header, it will be included from multiple files but the anonymous namespace is unique for every file. That means the type doesn't have the same definition everywhere.

Solution: move the relevant code to a .cpp file.

Comment: Could you please shed some light on what is anonymous in this `typedef` context. I could not really get anything out of it. That would really help me.

Comment: This is global header, I shall not be able to move to a source file. Is there a way to completely disable all warnings for a piece of code, despite compiling with `-Wall -Werror`. I tried `#pragma GCC disagnostic ignored "-Wall"` `#pragma GCC disagnostic ignored "-Werror"` does not help.

Comment: @Panch: `-Wall` and `-Werror` aren't specific warnings, but `#pragma GCC diagnostic warning -Wxyz` disables the specific warning `xyz`.I think this is `-Wsubobject-linkage`.

Comment: you are right. IT is `-Wsubobject-linkage` but unfortunately, the compiler gcc 4.8.2 does not recognize that. may be, should be available in the higher version. Please some one correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I would advice to be more careful; not just try to silence this warning, it is *for real* -- just the compiler can not tell if there is actual danger or not. The linker really treats anonymous objects as distinct entities on each usage, which can be a lingering danger, once such a type is used with static data, shared over several compilation units and especially with initialisation. I have been bitten quite badly with a variation of that situation....